# DelegateCommand creation, in Constructor or in Property

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I've seen multiple examples of DelegateCommands being created in either the constructor or within the property itself. I'm wondering if there is any advantage of doing it in the constructor as I've been doing it within the property to keep track of it easier.

(Using Prism, Silverlight4 and SimpleMVVM Toolkit in my case)

```
    private DelegateCommand _cmdLogin;
    public DelegateCommand CmdLogin
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cmdLogin == null)
            {
                _cmdLogin = new DelegateCommand(this.Login, this.CanLogIn);
            }
            return _cmdLogin;
        }
    }
```

VS

```
    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        this.LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.Login, this.CanLogin);
    }
    public DelegateCommand LoginCommand { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same thought as you Suiko6272 on this.

I ended up going with your second solution in the end.  however i did use this mechanism in my property gets for quite a while

```
private DelegateCommand _cmdLogin;
public DelegateCommand CmdLogin
{
    get { return _cmdLogin??(_cmdLogin = new DelegateCommand(this.Login, this.CanLogIn));}
}
```

The above code lazy loads the delegatecommand and is only 1 line of code.

I ended up going with your second solution because it is the clearest/easiest for other coders to read.

Comment: Did not know about the Null-Coalesce operator (??). Thanks for the new shorthand.